# Unable to create secret in kubernetes: "Secret is invalid: data[.dockerconfigjson]: Invalid value: "<secret contents redacted>": invalid character 'e'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong with my kubernetes secret yaml and why its not able to successfully create one programatically?

I am trying to programmatically create a secret in Kubernetes cluster with credentials to pull an image from a private registry but it is failing with the following:

```
"Secret "secrettest" is invalid: data[.dockerconfigjson]: Invalid value: "<secret contents redacted>": invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of value"
```

This is the yaml I tried to use to create the secret with. It is yaml output from a secret previously created in my kubernetes cluster using the command line except without a few unnecessary properties. So I know this is valid yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJoZWxsb3dvcmxkLmF6dXJlY3IuaW8iOnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJoZWxsbyIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoid29ybGQiLCJhdXRoIjoiYUdWc2JHODZkMjl5YkdRPSJ9fX0=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secrettest
  namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

This is the decoded value of the ".dockerconfigjson" property which seems to be throwing the error but not sure why if the value is supposed to be encoded per documentation:

```
{"auths":{"helloworld.azurecr.io":{"username":"hello","password":"world","auth":"aGVsbG86d29ybGQ="}}}
```

According to the documentation, my yaml is valid so Im not sure whats the issue:
[Customize secret yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdl2H.png)

**Note: I tried creating the Secret using the Kubernetes client and "PatchNamespacedSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync" in C#**

Referenced documentaion: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue. I was trying to create the Secret object using

```
Yaml.LoadAllFromString()
```

which was double encoding my `.dockerconfigjson` value. The weird part was the if the value wasnt encoded, it would fail. So I had to just manually create the Secret object instead of reading from a yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting same error. I was using base64 encoded value for `.dockerconfigjson`. Don't use base64 encoded value use

> {
> "auths": {
> "dummy.azurecr.io": {
> "auth": "",
> "password": "",
> "username": ""
> }
> } }

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar error when I was trying to create secret using client-go.
The error actually tells that the encoded string has invalid e at the beginning of the value (so may be it's expecting '{' this at the beginning ).To solve this, the value should not be encoded into base64. Just use it as it is and that will be encoded later.